# Integer memory representation

Tags: c, memory-management, integer, signed, unsigned-integer

As been told again and so that nehative numbers are represented by 2s complement while unsigned don't use that extra bit for signed convention. In case of integer we can represent both signed and unsigned. How in data type integer computer figures out which encoding scheme to pursue

Comment: the compiler decides, different code gets generated depending on whether you say 'int' or 'unsigned int'

Comment: its written in the program aka exe file

Comment: To the computer, it is just bits in a memory word.  Could be an int, a float, chars or a pointer, depending on the program.

Comment: How does the executable deal with a `double` differently from an `int`? It's the same idea... The compiler "reads" the source code and outputs the appropriate Assembly instructions that satisfy the requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Some operations (such as addition) work identically on both signed and unsigned integers.

But that's not the case for all operations. When right-shifting, we shift in zeroes for unsigned integers, and we shift in the sign bit for signed integers.

In these cases, the processor provides the means to achieve both operations. It's possible for the processor two offer two different instructions, or two variations of one.

But whatever the case, there is no decision making on the processor's part. The processor just executes the instructions selected by the compiler. It's up to the compiler to emit instructions that achieve the desired result based on the type of the values involved.